# ListView with image from server

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am doing an app which can view a `ListView` of item which contain item name, item price and item image. My images are store in a different folder. I want the `ListView` auto populated from server and load the image from server. Most of the online resource are hard-coded image link. What I want is the app is able to detect which image to load.

Comment: use volley network image loader see this http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2014/08/volley-network-image-loader.html

Answer (score 0):

You can basically try lazy loading of images. There are many good libraries for this task to happen

Like : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader and
       https://github.com/square/picasso